# HTML Option tag value property returns “undefined” with web-browser control in IE9

Tags: javascript, excel, winforms, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-9

The following is a javascript function on a webpage that I a navigate using the WebBrowser Control. I have two list boxes and an “Add” button in between. I select multiple items on the Left listbox and hit Add button so that those items will be copied to the right listbox. The javascript function called by the Add button is shown below.

PROBLEM: When I navigate the page on the WebBrowser Control(the version doesn’t matter), I see the following problem:

```
selList.options[j].value returns “undefined” . 

selList.options[j].text does return the correct text for the OPTION element.
```

The expected value of the selected OPTION should be  something like "11187|1".(It is simply looking for value property of OPTION html element). Note that selList.options[j].selected also returns valid “true” or “false” value.

This does not happen in IE 6, IE7 or IE8.
This does not happen in the IE 9 browser.
This only happens when using the WebBrowser control on a form from within Excel (VBA) on a machine with IE9. 
Oddly, this does NOT happen when using the webbrowser control in a .NET application & IE9.
It seems to be restricted to using the control from within Excel.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    function getSelectionString(selList) 
    {
      var aSelections = new Array();
      var listLength = selList.options.length;
      //alert("list Length "+listLength);
      for(var j=0; j < listLength; j++)
      {
            if(selList.options[j].selected) 
            {
                 var sItem = selList.options[j].value; //sItem returns “undefined” !!!
                  aSelections.push(sItem);
            }
  }
  return aSelections.join(",");
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

--SAMPLE of select tag for source select list—

```
<select name=”srcList”>

<option value='44725|1'>1st Auto & Cas Ins Co (44725-P)</option>
<option value='10750|1'>1st Choice Auto Ins Co (10750-P)</option>
<option value='35700|1'>2 10 Home Buyers Warranty of VA (35700-P)</option>
<option value='11187|1'>2-10 Hbw of NV Inc (11187-P)</option>

</select>
```

Comment: How are you **calling** the "getSelectionString()" function?

Comment: it was called by another javascript function which gets called upon clicking "Add" button on the page. This function goes through all the OPTIONs, see which ones are selected, creates a ',' seperated string of OPTION's value property (like "44725|1,11187|1") and returns it. All of this works fine on IE browser. But when I use WebBrowser Control through Excel VBA, this function sees value property of selected OPTION as "undefined" and hence it returns just "","".

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with a webbrowsercontrol in a VB.Net Word add-in. On a Citrix server (W2K8 R2) with IE9, the value of dropdownlists were undefined on (Ajax) postbacks. The same control however worked fine within a Outlook add-in on the same server, and in the normal IE9 browserwindow. After a waste of time checking the code, searching the web, I found out that there is a registry key that fixed our problem:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL]`

This key had this value "winword.exe"=dword:00000001 and Outlook.exe was not available in the key. So after setting the value to "winword.exe"=dword:00000000, everything worked fine.

See also:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927377

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vastly simplified html file. Please save as test.html

```
<html>
<script>
    function submitClick(form) {
      var aSelections = new Array();
      var selectionList = form.selectionList;
      var listLength = selectionList.options.length;

      alert("list Length "+listLength);
      for(var j=0; j < listLength; j++){
            //alert("got ["+j+"] "+selectionList.options[j].value);
            if(selectionList.options[j].selected) {
                alert("got Selected["+j+"] - value is - "+selectionList.options[j].value);
                var sItem = selectionList.options[j].value;
                aSelections.push(sItem);
           }
        }
        aSelections.join(",");
        alert("Selected values "+aSelections);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form name="selectForm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><select name="selectionList" size="12" style="width:390" styleClass="companySelection" multiple="true">
<option value='44725|1'>1st Auto & Cas Ins Co (44725-P)</option>
<option value='10750|1'>1st Choice Auto Ins Co (10750-P)</option>
<option value='35700|1'>2 10 Home Buyers Warranty of VA (35700-P)</option>
<option value='11187|1'>2-10 Hbw of NV Inc (11187-P)</option>
</select><br>
</td><td>
<input class=insButton type="button"  value="Add >"
         onClick="submitClick(this.form)" />
</td><td>

</td>
<br>

</form>
</html>
```

Setup:

On a machine with IE9, in Excel (version doesnt matter), drop an ActiveX commandButton.

Drop a webbrowser control.

In the callback for the commandbutton1, call the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     WebBrowser1.Navigate ("C:\temp\test.html")
 End Sub
```

To Reproduce:

IE 9 (works): Launch test.html in IE 9.0. Use your mouse to select all 4 items on the left listbox and click on Add.

You will get a count, and all of the values will be displayed.

Via App (doesn’t work): Launch Excel. Click on the commandbutton. This will load the page in the webbrowser control. Use your mouse to select all 4 items in the left hand box. You will get a count, but this time, the value will say “undefined”

Any Answers? Anyone seen why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue some time ago. Unfortunately I found nothing regarding this issue in Internet. I any case I did a workaround. It is magic because value is undefined itself but available from collection of attributes. Please use the following solution if it works for you.

```
    function getOptionValue(opt) {
           var val;
           if (opt) {
                  if (typeof (opt.value) == "undefined") {
                         if (opt.attributes && opt.attributes["value"]) {
                               val = opt.attributes["value"].value;
                         }
                  }
                  else
                         val = opt.value;
           }
           return val;
    }
```

I believe its caused by different behavior between IE web browser and instance of IE web browser that was opened from Excel. The different interfaces are used for same HTML option element (`DispHTMLWndOptionElement` and `DispHTMLOptionElement`).